# how to improve the running time for knapsack problem from O(N*M) to O(N)?

Tags: knapsack-problem

I'm currently doing a algorithm assignment for knapsack problem, the question is as follow:

The size of knapsack is M, and there are N items each with a integer value and integer weight, we need to figure out the optimal maxium weight that we can put into the knapsack.

I'm using dynamic programming to solve this problem and save the result only for current and the previous loops which takes M*2 space, although it saves space, the time complexity for it is still O(M*N) as there two for loops, is there any way to improve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a pseudo-polynomial order which means it will take same time no matter how we design the dynamic algorithm approach because the knapsack problem is among np classical problems.
Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).